# Comparing two tables with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have two tables each in different DB on the same server ...with multiple columns in SQL.

I need to fetch the records where the value of one of the column I use is present in TableA and not in TableB. This column is alphanumeric (BIGINT) in TableA while it is different in TableB it is ShortDescription(varchar(100))

TableB column's value is ONLY numbers same as Table A column but without characters (for example 123) while TableA column value can contain for example "ab123"

Now if value "abc123" in TableA is present in Table A and value "123" is not in Table B, then I should get that record from table A. If 123 is present in Table B for that column, then I shouldn't fetch.

How to do?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need PATINDEX to find the numbers from TableA.Column1 and then match it with TableB.Column2. Below is the query for you:

Select Column1 FROM TableA WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB WHERE SUBSTRING(CAST(Column1 AS VARCHAR), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', CAST(Column1 AS VARCHAR)), LEN(Column1))=Column2)

I am assuming you do not have a common column between two tables. Otherwise you can use the common column to join and put the PATINDEX statement in WHERE clause.

Comment: You are close, but not sure if thats exactly the one I want. Let me try

Comment: I get syntax error near equal in the " LEN(Column1)=Column2)"

Comment: I have common columns (Other column).

Comment: We need some casting there. I have updated the  answer.

Comment: sorry, it looks good, you are right. My query is still running, let you know in a moment :)

Comment: Quick question, should it not be != rather than =?

Comment: I mean not exists? rather than using exists?

Comment: This query returns Column1 from TableA if number from Column1 exists in Column2of TableB. That is why I am using EXISTS. Use NOT EXISTS if it is otherwise.

Comment: Its not fetching desired results I know its not your query problem but can you make a simple one. I think I can tell you this, I have a common column. I am NOT comparing that values as they both have same values and used ONLY for joining. There is one other column that has the above logic of substring etc you did. Can you please help?

Comment: WAIT! BIGINT cannot store alphanumeric value. Please check your data type of columns and come back with the question.

Comment: I queried the subquery and found it only results in no result, I mean the substring part select itself. Something wrong I reckon

Comment: The column that is ShortDescription(Varchar(80)) it says in substring we use. Pls help... I think its not correctly querying

Comment: The query assumes that Column1 is the one holding alphanumeric value and Column2 is holding numeric value. If it is not so then swap them.

Comment: I did swap, but no luck. The problem is, I am even trying to select TOP 1 Substring( whatever you gave) and that returns no row at all. Not even that column value. How come? Say if abc123 is present, then I should get 123 right? the inner subquery doesnt return anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. It makes things simple by joining the two tables, then utilizing the `WHERE` clause. I'll just call the common column between the two tables "Id" for the join:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.Id 
WHERE TableA.Column1 = "ab123" AND TableB.ShortDescription != "123";
```

Comment: No, thats easy if you have the value, but I dont have that value. I want to get records that are satisfying the scenario than the condition itself.

Comment: @Learner Can you expand on what you mean? I'm a little perplexed.